# Search all controllers in cakephp

Tags: javascript, forms, cakephp, controller

I need to perform a query on any controller from a single form and I try this:

```
<select id="control">
        <option value="labs">Laboratórios</option>
        <option value="computers">Computadores</option>
        <option value="hists">Históricos</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#control").change(function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php 
        $controller = '<script>document.write(value);</script>';
        print_r($controller);
        $base_url = array('controller' => $controller, 'action' => 'index' );
        echo $this->Form->create("Filter",array('url' => $base_url, 'class' => 'filter'));
        echo $this->Form->input("search", array('label' => 'Pesquisa', 'placeholder' => "Pesquisa..."));
        echo $this->Form->submit("Pesquisar");
        echo $this->Html->link("Reset",$base_url);
        echo $this->Form->end(); 
    ?>
```

But the variable $controller has the string "`<script>document.write(value);</script>`", how to fix this? or have another way to do this...

Comment: What I understood as of now is, you want to call the controller on the  basis of $("#control") value. Which means $("#control").value is the controller name. Is it correct?

Comment: yes. "labs", "computers" and "hists" are the controllers names.

Comment: you can't add dynamic javascript value to php. But you can change it in the html (output), may be in the form actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `model` instead `controller` -

```
<?php 
    $base_url = array('controller' => 'any_controller', 'action' => 'any_action' );
    echo $this->Form->create("Filter",array('url' => $base_url, 'class' => 'filter'));
    $models = array('Model1' => 'Model1', 'Model2' => 'Model2', 'Model3' => 'Model3');
    echo $this->Form->input("model", array('label' => 'Model', 'options' => $models));
    echo $this->Form->input("search", array('label' => 'Pesquisa', 'placeholder' => "Pesquisa..."));
    echo $this->Form->submit("Pesquisar");
    echo $this->Html->link("Reset",$base_url);
    echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

and in the `any_action()` of `any_controller you will get all the value.

```
function any_action() {
    $model = $this->request->data['Filter']['model'];
    //instantiate the model
    $modelInit = ClassRegistry::init($model);
    //build search conditions depending on the other data
    $condition = array(...);
    $result = $modelInit->find('all', $condition);
    //set the result and redirect to your page`
}
```

Comment: Thanks 'sgt', your suggestion worked. I had already created a function, was only pass the parameter of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the form action on change of dropdown. I don't think you need PHP here.

```
<select id="control">
    <option value="labs">Laboratórios</option>
    <option value="computers">Computadores</option>
    <option value="hists">Históricos</option>
</select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //This will change the action on change of dropdown value
        $("#control").change(function(){
            var hostname = window.location.hostname;
            var controller = $(this).val();
            $('#filterForm').attr('action', 'http://'+hostname+'/'+controller+'/index');
        });
    });
</script>
<?php         
    $base_url = array('controller' => $controller, 'action' => 'index' );
    echo $this->Form->create("Filter",array('url' => $base_url, 'class' => 'filter','id'=>'filterForm'));
    echo $this->Form->input("search", array('label' => 'Pesquisa', 'placeholder' => "Pesquisa..."));
    echo $this->Form->submit("Pesquisar");
    echo $this->Html->link("Reset",$base_url);
    echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

Hope this will work for you..